# Opening and closing add in after adding or deleting an element

Tags: c#, revit-api

I want to open an Addin and execute a function within after adding or deleting an element.

This is the current code:

App.cs

```
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using System;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;


namespace RevitRadiatorAddin
{
    public class App : IExternalApplication
    {
        Assembly assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication app)
        {
            String panelName = "Radiator Calculation";

            RibbonPanel radiatorRibbon = app.CreateRibbonPanel(panelName);
            PushButton ribbonButton = (PushButton)radiatorRibbon.AddItem(new PushButtonData("Radiator", "Open Radiator\n Calculation Addin", assemblyPath.Location, "RevitRadiatorAddin.MainWindowControl"));
            //DC: fixed copy of .ico-file into AppData-folder
            ribbonButton.LargeImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(assemblyPath.Location.Replace(".dll",".ico"), UriKind.Absolute));
            ribbonButton.ToolTip = "Click me!";
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

The Add in calculates the heating output of radiators and the heating need of a room. I basically need an "action performed" after adding or deleting a radiator.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a dynamic updater derived from the [IUpdater interface](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/4cdaf502-fc25-8f18-7618-8448cce33d11.htm) using the functionality provided by the [DMU or dynamic model updater framework](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.31).